# React: How can I control a list of <input> with state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's a minimal working example of a component with a form of inputs created from a list, and one created from a single value:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    value: 'single value',
    values: ['one', 'two'],
  }

  render() {
    let test = this.state.values.map( (v, i) => {
      return <input
        key={ v }
        value={ v }
        onChange={ (e) => {
          let values = this.state.values;
          values[i] = e.target.value;
          this.setState({ values });
        } }
      />;
    } )

    return <div>
      <form>
        { test }
      </form>
      <form>
        <input
          value={ this.state.value }
          onChange={ (e) => this.setState({ value: e.target.value }) }
        />
      </form>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

When the user edits the third input field ('single value'), everything is fine. The user types something, the state updates, everyone is happy.

When the user edits either of the first two input fields however, the cursor loses focus immediately after the state is updated. To edit this field, the user must click on the field after any letter has been put in.

How do I solve this? Is there a way to prevent the component from blurring the `<input>`, or is there a better way to solve this?

I don't know how to record my screen and make a GIF from it. If you did not understand what I mean I suggest you create a React app with `npx create-react-app my-app` and edit `my-app/src/App.js` to my code example.

Comment: `key = {i}` -- try this and let me know. I believe it's losing focus because the key is changing on update

Comment: @TKoL [Index as a key is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318), but it seems to be the root of the problem.

Comment: True, but it's only an anti-pattern contextually. In this context, you've hardcoded an array of length two into 'values' -- if you can rely on that being a constant, then realistically there's no reason why the first value shouldn't just have a key of 0, and the second one a key of 1. It's an antipattern because it makes more complicated things difficult or impossible (eg if you wanted to sort your values, the keys would now be mixed up and ruin your application). But given certain constants, it's actually fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the value as a `key`, for each new value you get a new `key` which react "thinks" its a new element thus re-mount the element and you loose the focus

[Read more about keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```
let test = this.state.values.map( (v, i) => {
      return <input
        key={ v }
        value={ v }
        onChange={ (e) => {
          let values = this.state.values;
          values[i] = e.target.value;
          this.setState({ values });
        } }
      />;
    } )
```

Not sure if you can change the `state` structure, but i would go for a different approach and create a `form` object and give the `name` and `key` attributes according to the object's key.

Example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    form: {
      name: "",
      userName: "",
      age: ""
    },
    externalValue: ""
  };

  onFormInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { form } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      form: {
        ...form,
        [target.name]: target.value
      }
    });
  };

  onInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({ [target.name]: target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { form } = this.state;
    let test = Object.entries(form).map(([key, value]) => {
      return (
        <input
          key={key}
          name={key}
          placeholder={key}
          value={value}
          onChange={this.onFormInputChange}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <form>{test}</form>
        <form>
          <input
            name="externalValue"
            placeholder="externalValue"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: That is indeed the problem. But what can I use as a key then? [Using list index as key is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Comment: A key must be unique between siblings, in your case there is no `id` or anything beside the `index` that can act as a `key`. note that react by default uses the `index` as a `key` when no `key` provided. The only reason for you to use the index as a `key` is to bypass the warning for not passing a key to each child.

Comment: The blog post I linked to earlier suggests I use a `.id` prop. I think a solution to my problem is to create such a prop from the inital value of `state.values`.

Answer (score 0):

In `render()`, you are mapping the state 'values' to the `<input>`. React identifies the component by its key. 
1. Initially you have `['one', 'two']` in 'values' state. And its corresponding keys will be `['one', 'two']`. 
2. If suppose you change the value of one of the input element as "one1". Then you will update the  states and while mapping you will have a new key as "one1" which is different from previous key "one", so React considers it as a new element and loses the focus.

You try with this code

```
let test = this.state.values.map( (v, i) => {
      return <input
        key={ `key${i}` }
        value={ v }
        onChange={ (e) => {
          let values = this.state.values;
          values[i] = e.target.value;
          this.setState({ values });
        } }
      />;
    } )
```

You can check the code here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9lstyj